# Sort the elements before inserting them into the table

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem sorting the elements in the array based on the variable number. Once sorted, they must be inserted into the table. I try to use sort on item but I get the error.

I get the following error:

*item.sort is not a function*

How can I solve?

```js
let myArr = [{
    type : "Image", 
    id_a: '123456', 
    number: 2, 
    id: 2,
    },{
    type: 'Text', 
    id_a: '123456', 
    number: 4, 
    id: 4
    },{
    type: 'Testo', 
    id_a: '564312', 
    number: 1, 
    id: 1},{
    type: 'Title', 
    id_a: '123456', 
    number: 3, 
    id: 3
    }
    ]
    
var id_url=123456;
var results = {};
for (var i = 0, len = myArr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var id_art = myArr[i].id_a;
    if (id_art == id_url) {
        results[i] = myArr[i];
        }
        
}

console.log(results);

 
Object.entries(results).forEach(item => {
    item = item[1];
    console.log(item)
    item.sort(function (a, b) {
           if (a.number != b.number) {
               return (a.number - b.number);
  }
 });
    let child = document.createElement("tr");
                 child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.number}</td>
                    <td>${item.type}</td>`;
                    document.querySelector('#my-table').appendChild(child);
 })
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

It's easier to sort.

```js
      const filterList = myArr.filter((now) => now.id_a == id_url);
      const sortList = filterList.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
      const results = { ...sortList };

      for (const item of sortList) {
        let child = document.createElement("tr");
        child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.number}</td>
                    <td>${item.type}</td>`;
        document.querySelector("#my-table").appendChild(child);
      }
```

Comment: I don't need to sort myArr but the results I get in results

Comment: @elfuso In addition to the expression, is a results object variable necessary?
If necessary, I will add it to the content.

Comment: yes, result is necessary

Comment: @elfuso Is it the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting function is correct but sort is a built-in function for arrays taking a function as the parameter. You can use it like below:

```js
let myArr = [{
    type : "Image", 
    id_a: '123456', 
    value: 'moto_guzzi_v100_mandello.jpg', 
    number: 2, 
    id: 2,
    },{
    type: 'Text', 
    id_a: '123456', 
    value: 'The star of the Piaggio group stand is without doubt ... Discover all his secrets with our video', 
    number: 4, 
    id: 4
    },{
    type: 'Testo', 
    id_a: '564312', 
    value: 'Let find out together with our video', 
    number: 1, 
    id: 1},{
    type: 'Title', 
    id_a: '123456', 
    value: 'Moto Guzzi V100 Mandello, the queen of EICMA 2021', 
    number: 3, 
    id: 3
    }
    ]
    
var id_url=123456;
var results = {};
for (var i = 0, len = myArr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var id_art = myArr[i].id_a;
    if (id_art == id_url) {
        results[i] = myArr[i];
        }
        
}

console.log(results);

 
console.log("Before Sort", myArr);
const sortedArr =  myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
           if (a.number != b.number) {
               return (a.number - b.number);
  }
 });
console.log("After Sort", sortedArr);
```

Comment: how do i use it in the foreach?

Comment: You can't use because .sort works on Arrays when you use forEach you get Objects one by one. Why do you want to use it in forEach? Maybe you can sort first then use forEach to do what you want to do?

Comment: yes right, I have to order first and then use the foreach